# Zend Framework 2 multiple routes for pagination not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-framework2

I am trying to set two different routes to handle pagination of data, for instance:

```
'error' => [
      'type' => 'Segment',
          'options' => [
          'route' => '/error[/:action][/:id][page/:page]',
          'constraints' => [
              'page' => '[0-9]*',
               'id'   => '[0-9]*',
           ],

          'defaults' => [ 
              'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Error',
              'action'     => 'index',
          ],
      ],
],



'paginator' => [
      'type'    => 'Segment',
      'options' => [
           'route' => '/blog/list-entries/[page/:page]',
           'constraints' => [
                'page' => '[0-9]*',
           ],

           'defaults' => [
                'controller'    => 'Admin\Controller\Blog',
                'action'        => 'list-entries',
           ],
       ],
],
```

In the error route, the paginator works for the first set of data, but when I try to go to the next page to view more data it uses /blog/list-entries/page/2 instead of the /error/[/:action][/:id][page/:page] route. Is the paginator route becoming the default route for more data?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, I was passing the wrong paginator route in the view. Thanks!